# Vimeo App direct upload from client device using PHP

Tags: php, api, upload, vimeo

after reading a lot of pages I couldn't find out if it is possible to upload a video with the PHP SDK directly to an Vimeo account? I found a lot of examples using a post option from a server uri or a pull option from an url.

```
$file_name = "{path_to_a_video_on_the_file_system}";
$uri = $myvimeo->upload($file_name, array(
```

But I would need to directly upload from a website form (users device) to vimeo. Is this possible and may you have a link to a code example?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The form based approach described [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#form-approach) is the easiest approach for this.

You can make this request from the PHP library using `request`, i.e.

```
$response = $lib->request('/me/videos', [
  "upload" => [
    "approach" => "post",
    "redirect_url" => "{url}"
  ]
], 'POST');
```

This will return an HTML form in `$response['body']['upload']['form']`.

Comment: thank you this info I have never seen:
This will return an HTML form in $response['body']['upload']['form']

Comment: okay thanks for the answer, then I know that it is really possible and can go on forward! 
however I lack the know how and I must research, how now the selected file from the user client presumably comes into the last 'Post' I assume.

Comment: Using this method, you would not need to fetch a file from the client - the form will upload directly to Vimeo.

So when a user indicates the desire to upload, perform the action indicated above and display the form to them. They will pick a video from their computer, it will upload to Vimeo, and on completion they'll be navigated back to `redirect_url`.

Comment: thanks that helped to not thinking in wrong direction that the form somehow had to be created on my side :-)  
now all makes sense to me, that the request to vimeo already creates a blank video and gives back the form that is waiting for the video content. And also that the vimeo video_uri/videoID is given back with the redirect_url
thanks for help!